# Remove double quotes from ruby loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a ruby on rails web app and in my view I have the following code:

```
<div id="glmol02" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; background-color: black;"></div> <textarea id="glmol02_src" style="display: none;">
<% @name.coords.each_with_index do |coord, i| %>
  <%= coord.atom %>
<% end %>
END
</textarea>
```

When I look at my web page, there are double quotes around the whole for loop, how can I remove those double quotes?

```
<div></div>
<textarea>
" entry1
  entry2
  ...
  entry100 "
</textarea>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's inspector (for example, other browsers might do this too) adds pseudo-quotes to elements if they're beginning or ending with a whitespace/tabs/etc to indicate their presence. Similar behaviour can apply to `<p>` and `<div>`.

Have you checked the website's actual source with `CTRL+U`, or are you just using the inspector?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this helped a lot. My issue actually ended up being due to incorrect spacing for the strings it was returning not playing nicely with the GLmol plugin I was using.  You made me realize that I was barking up the wrong tree, thanks!